# Usage of Gremlin's 'or' in Scala

Tags: database, scala, gremlin

I'm looking how to make use of the `or` with gremlin-scala, thought this would work:

```
graph.V.or(_.has("type", "this"), _.has("type", "that"))
```

Thanks

Comment: what did you expect and what was the result?

Comment: I'm looking at `GremlinScalaPipeline`, which I'm guessing `graph.V` is, and the definition of `or` is: `def or(pipes: Pipe[E, _]*)`.  This seems to indicate that the `or` method takes a var args of instances of `Pipe`.  It looks like you are trying to invoke it using high-order functions (assumed by the user of `_`) and I don't see any flavor of `or` that matches that.  Not sure if that's your problem or not.

Comment: @mrhobo this was not compiling.  
@cmbaxter Humm, I guess then I should call something that returns a Pipe:
`graph.V.or(new GremlinScalaPipeline[Vertex, Vertex].has("type", "this"), new GremlinScalaPipeline[Vertex, Vertex].has("type", "that"))`
That seems very complicated.